# Difficulty creating the mute command - DIscord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I'm having problems making my mute command. I tested it but it doesn't create the Muted role. Maybe I made some mystakes in the over-writing section. I wish someone could help me. Anyway, here's my code:

```
if (message.content.startsWith(config.prefix + "mute")) {
      let toMute = message.mentions.users.first();
 
      if (!message.guild.member(message.author).hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) {
        return message.channel.send('You do not have the permission for mute users!');
      }
      if (!message.guild.member(client.user).hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) {
        return message.channel.send("I don’t have the permission for mute users!");
      }
      if (!toMute) {
        return message.channel.send("You need to ping a user or the user can't be found!");
      }
      let mutedRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(mR => mR.name === "Muted");
      if (!mutedRole) {
        try {
          mutedRole = await message.guild.createRole({
            name: "Muted",
            color: "#000000",
            permissions: []
          });
 
          message.guild.channels.forEach(async (channel, id) => {
            await channel.overwritePermissions(mutedRole, {
              SEND_MESSAGES: false,
              ADD_REACTIONS: false
            })
          });
 
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err.stack);
        }
      }
      if (message.guild.member(toMute).roles.cache.has(mutedRole.id)) return message.channel.send("This user is already muted!");
      await message.guild.member(toMute).roles.add(mutedRole);
      message.channel.send(`${toMute} got muted by <@${message.author.id}> `)
      let {guild} = message;
      toMute.send(`You got muted in **${guild.name}** by ${message.author}`)
  }
```

and I'm getting this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXv6w.png).

Can someone help me fixing please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It says you typed 'msg' somewhere. Wherever it is, you may need to change it

Comment: There's no `msg` in the code you provided. But you are using `message` everywhere in your code so maybe you are accidentally using `msg` somewhere

Comment: Thanks but I don't see msg in my code so I'm getting a bit dumb with this. Anyway, thanks for posting my comment!